React + Django with Docker-Compose on AWS EC2: "Invalid Host Header" When Using Domain Name
I am hosting a web application using React (frontend) and Django (backend) on AWS EC2. The application is containerized with Docker and Docker Compose. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy to route traffic from port 443 to the React app on port 3000 and serve the app over HTTPS.
The app works fine when I access it using the public IP (https://), but when I use the configured domain name (https://testportal.com), I get the following error:
Invalid Host Header
The app works if I set DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true in my environment, but this is not a secure solution for production.
Here are the relevant configurations:
Docker Compose (docker-compose.yml):
version: "3"

services:
  react-app:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=16384
      - NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  django-app:
    build:
      context: ./backend/webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    environment:
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge


React Dockerfile:
FROM node:21.7.3

ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=16384 --openssl-legacy-provider"

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]


Environment File (.env):
HOST=testportal.com
HTTPS=true
PORT=3000


Nginx Configuration:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.testportal.com testportal.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.testportal.com testportal.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testportal.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testportal.com/privkey.pem;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256";
    
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;  # This sets the header to the correct value
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}


/etc/hosts File:
127.0.0.1 localhost
x.x.x.x testportal.com
x.x.x.x www.testportal.com


What I’ve Tried:

Setting DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true resolves the issue, but this isn't suitable for production.
Verified that the domain points to the correct IP.
Nginx appears to be routing correctly since the domain resolves, but React throws the "Invalid Host Header" error.

Goal:
I want to properly configure my application to securely handle requests from the domain (https://testportal.com) without disabling host checks.
